# Why my Jquery function not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this jquery function ---

```
function domail_slide_settings(obj)
{
  $("div#" + obj).toggle();
}
```

and when I execute it like this ---

```
<a href="#" onclick="domail_slide_settings('toggle')" id="toggle" >Toggle</a>
```

It doesn't toggle! Does anyone have any ideas about this. Please let me know, it would be a great help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're defeatng the use of jquery if you're still adding that function in a onclick. create an external js and use $("#toggle").click()

Comment: what does your `div` html look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with

```
  $("#" + obj).toggle();
```

and point it to a < div > element, instead of an anchor

Comment: how is `# + obj` correct? obj will be the anchor tag object so prefixing with `#` should not be necessary/work

Comment: Hey can you see this jsfiddle and edit it, because it is not working. I don't know the reason. Maybe you should know. Please help me.
http://jsfiddle.net/NkXUv/

Comment: Hey this worked. But the thing is I want it to be a function so I can use with different elements too. Got some ideas!

Answer (score 4):

ID attributes **must** be unique in a HTML document, otherwise you will run into unwanted side-effects.  From the looks of it, your `<a>` element with the click handler has the same `id` attribute as the `div#toggle` element you're toggling.  This would almost certainly be a problem in some browsers.

Try changing the ID of your `<a>` element to be unique:

```
<a href="#" onclick="domail_slide_settings('toggle')" id="toggle_div" >Toggle</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">Toggle</a>
<div id="div_toggle"></div>
```

and this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#toggle").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#div_" + this.id).toggle();
        // or $(this).next().toggle(); depending on your markup
    });
});
```

I bet you're using the same id for your `<a>` tag and your `<div>` tag which should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

or you can try

```
$('#' + obj).parent().toggle();
```

^^

Answer (score 0):

the result of your string concatenation - "div#toggle" - is selecting a div with id toggle, instead of your anchor.

I think you meant to select it as:

```
$("#toggle").parent()
```

or, if you want really what the anchor itself, use this:

```
$("#toggle")
```

In any case, since your function is an onclick handler (directly through the browser though, not using jQuery event api), you might as well do this:

```
function domail_slide_settings() {
    $(this).parent().toggle()
    // or this.toggle();
}
```

Comment: Wrong.  It's valid, but it won't match his element.